# Configuring suitable target with CMake for gcov

Tags: c++, cmake, gcov, gcovr

I have followed this link(https://jhbell.com/using-cmake-and-gcov) to integrate gcov in CMake. But it is only working when all the test cases are passed. My few of the Google test cases are getting failed, so cmake is stopping generating the coverage report.
[image]

Is there any way to change build system behavior for CMake?

Comment: Your links are broken.

Comment: I have updated the links. pls. check